# How to remove duplicates in particular set of data?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, time-complexity

Let's suppose we have two childs who want to get same number or coins (coin nominals 1,2,6,12). Childs don't care about the value.
Example container of permutations which I want to share between two childs:

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
{1, 1, 2, 2},
{1, 2, 1, 2},
{1, 2, 2, 1},
{2, 1, 1, 2},
{2, 1, 2, 1},
{2, 2, 1, 1}
```

Now I`d like to have collections without duplicates:

```
child A     child B
2 2         1 1 
2 1         2 1 
1 1         2 2 
1 1 1       1 1 1
```

That permutations are wrong:

```
1 2 1 2 
1 2 2 1 
2 1 1 2
```

because

```
child A     child B
1 2         1 2
```

is permutation of

```
child A     child B
2 1         2 1
```

which we already have. These collections: `1 2 2 1` and `2 1 1 2` are permutations, as well.

My solution is here, works correctly for that particular input but if you add more coins with different nominals, it doesn't!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> permutations = 
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 2, 2},
        {1, 2, 1, 2},
        {1, 2, 2, 1},
        {2, 1, 1, 2},
        {2, 1, 2, 1},
        {2, 2, 1, 1}
    };
    vector<pair<unordered_multiset<int>, unordered_multiset<int>>> childSubsets;

    for(const auto &currentPermutation : permutations)
    {
            size_t currentPermutationSize = currentPermutation.size();
            size_t currentPermutationHalfSize = currentPermutationSize / 2;
            //left
            unordered_multiset<int> leftSet;

            for(int i=0;i<currentPermutationHalfSize;++i)
                leftSet.insert(currentPermutation[i]);

            bool leftSubsetExist = false;
            for(const auto &subset : childSubsets)
            {
                if(subset.first == leftSet)
                {
                    leftSubsetExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //right
            unordered_multiset<int> rightSet;

            for(int i = currentPermutationHalfSize; i < currentPermutationSize; ++i)
                rightSet.insert(currentPermutation[i]);

            bool rightSubsetExist = false;
            for(const auto &subset : childSubsets)
            {
                if(subset.second == rightSet)
                {
                    rightSubsetExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //summarize
            if(!leftSubsetExist || !rightSubsetExist) childSubsets.push_back({leftSet, rightSet});
    }
    cout << childSubsets.size() << endl;
}
```

**How to change the solution to make optimal and less complex?**

Comment: *How to remove duplicates in particular set of data?* -- Don't store duplicates in the first place.  Use `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: std::unordered_set doesn`t allowed to contain duplicates. In that algorithm is possible to have e.g. 2,2 in one set.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
if (leftSubsetExist) 
  continue;
```

after first cycle (as optimization)

Could you add some "wrong" permutations (with another coins)?